# ASP.NET or Javascript library to paint custom defined parts on USA map in colors?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to display the map of the USA with state outlines in a web page. I also want to have predefined zones or parts of the map and have each part in a certain color. The parts do not change per request which means these parts could be defined by a single time process and what changes per request is just the solid color.

I am looking for an ASP.NET or Javascript Library or tool whcih produces such a map. The map can be a static image or interactive based on HTML5. Flash would be my last resort. The library should have an easy way to define the parts (polygons?). I am envisioning a desktop tool where I can trace over the map by hand to0 define the p0arts and the tool would create the data points to be used later in the drawn map.

Comment: I am surprised Google search yielded no results. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is a desktop tool which can be used to load a map static image and to draw freehand polygons on the map for the regions. The final output (image + polygons) can be output to a single svg file which can be displayed in a web page.

I also used [svg2vml](http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/) to support IE8-.

Answer (score 1):

D3 has been used to do these kinds of tasks pretty well:

- http://d3js.org/
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

Comment: I don't think D3 has a tool to draw the polygons as I requested.

Comment: Did you look at the second link?  How is that different from your requirement?

Comment: Your second link is about zooming and positioning. It has nothing to do with defining custom polygons.

Comment: It's all custom polygons, declared in this file: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json

Comment: What was the tool used to define all those polygons?